# mysql, install phpmyadmin on amazon/bitnami

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, phpmyadmin, bitnami

Anyone who knows how to install the phpmyadmin?

I really don't know where do I start this is my first time installing phpmyadmin.

I will really appreciate if you post  a link that will point to a tutorial about it ;)

Thanks,
King Pangilinan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use BitNami in Amazon you can just launch a [BitNami LAMPStack AMI](http://bitnami.org/stack/lampstack#cloudImage) which already includes phpMyAdmin. Also if you launch a [BitNami Wordpress](http://bitnami.org/stacks), Joomla or any other php application will included phpMyAdmin.

Another option with is to launch any Linux image in Amazon and use a native installer for getting LAMP Stack installed.

In any case, once you have installed [this information](http://wiki.bitnami.org/Components/phpMyAdmin_and_phpPgAdmin) may be useful to you if you want to access remotely to phpMyAdmin.